# How to add and remove liquidity from uniswap3 using smart contract and sdk?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, uniswap

I am trying to build a web application using uniswap v3 for adding and removing the liquidity. I could able to add liquidity but for removing it I need a token, How to get it from uniswap?

Comment: Please edit the question show your code what have you tried so far, as the starting point, as otherwise the question is too open ended

Comment: I want to know how to fetch the token id from the uni swap pool to remove it.

Answer (score 4):

When you add liquidity on uniswap v3 an NFT is minted and sent to your address. The `Transfer` event is emitted which contains the `tokenId`. You can see an example [here on etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x60d8457a2a6fe10cb1c60d1fb9effbadbdc0aa92e2645f26e4acbb7dca43d6df).

To remove the liquidity, you have to listen for this event and `tokenId` and then submit the same `tokenId` to remove the liquidity by burning the NFT token. An [example here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x225d32c10d2ef9143f7ef7fcaba2d1911a845777e2fc4f42a9ae42d994d6642b).

Alternatively, you could query the `tokenOfOwnerByIndex` function on the [uni NFT contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88#readProxyContract) and iterate from 0->n to get all of the NFTs liquidity positions owned by a user. This will give you all the `tokenId`s of NFTs which the user owns.